# How to extend z-oerder action in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

I want do following thing in two steps:

1. set the actor scale 1.2 in 1 seconds,
2. and then set its z-order to top most

how I control this? if use

```
sequence(Action action1, Action action2)
```

there I must package z-order change to an action, is it?

I know in cocos2d its easy to finish these action to use block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the Z index is a bit out of scope for the actor `Actions`. You can do arbitrary things with the `Actions.run(Runnable)`.

```
    class ZIndexSetter implements Runnable {

    private int zIndex;
    private Actor actor;

    public ZIndexSetter(int zIndex, Actor actor) {
        this.zIndex = zIndex;
        this.actor = actor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        actor.setZIndex(zIndex);
    }

}
```

And then you can use it this way:

```
actor.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.scaleTo(1.2f, 1.2f, 1f), Actions.run(new ZIndexSetter(Integer.MAX_VALUE, actor));
```

But in total I'd suggest that if you have sophisticated sequences of Actions which also do more than just resizing, moving etc, you should have a look at the more powerful [Tween Engine](http://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/), which needs a bit more time to get things going, but once you implemented all `TweenAccessors` which you need, it gets very convenient and easy to use.

Comment: Tween Engine? its a 2d engin? I want to a fluent 2d effect in my app.

Comment: Tweening comes from "inbetweening". It's for interpolation between two states. Just the same like Actions do. You can do it with Actions on Actors, but they are a bit limited. With Tween Engine you can do interpolations also with anything else. Checkout the link, you don't need it, but it might be useful in your case.

Comment: @bellnas Yes it does, otherwise I wouldn't mention it. Actually it can be used in any random Java program. You need to implement the interface `TweenAccessor` in your own classes and then those classes can be interpolated via Tween Engine. When you use the setup UI to create the projects, it even offers you to also setup Tween Engine as well.